# How to force dark mode on Firefox for Android?

Tags: firefox-for-android

I am looking for a way to force dark mode on Firefox for Android.

I tried using [Dark mode](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/dark-mode-webextension/) add-on, but it doesn't work.

Is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Dark Background and Light Text](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/android/addon/dark-background-light-text/?src=search) add-on.

This is how it looks like using the mode (it's night time for me as I write). By toggling the `Aa` icon on the address bar, you can enable or disable it, select the global or select sites you want affected as also modify the default scheme

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@beeshyams' answer does not work as the add-on doesn't work on the android phone I have (Samsung Galaxy S10).

[Dark Reader](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/android/addon/darkreader/) is the only add-on I can find which works